# maximum value from values between two zeros

Tags: r, range, max

I have values in a column and would like to pick the maximum value from non-zero ranges in that column. A range is defined by non-zero values between two zeros. I am not sure if this explanation is right though. Kindly see the example below. I have done this is excel but I need to be able to do this in R and I am not sure of how to go about it. Any guide on where to start will be appreciated. My target is the column named "out".

```
ind<-c(0,0,0,0.4,0.6,0.7,0.7,0.9,0,0,0,1,3,10,0,0)
out<-c(0,0,0,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.9,0,0,0,10,10,10,0,0)
bbb<-data.frame (ind,out)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do it iteratively. Probably slow for big datasets.

```
m=c(0,0,0,0.1,0.6,0.3,0,0,0.2,0.1,0.2,0,0,0)
maxims=0
aux=NULL
pos=1
for (i in 1:length(m)){

  if (m[i]!=0){
    aux=c(aux,m[i])
  }
  if (m[i]==0 && length(aux)>0){
    maxims[pos]=max(aux)
    aux=NULL
    pos=pos+1
  }
}
> maxims
[1] 0.6 0.2
```

Answer (score 2):

It's always good to provide an example of your problem that can easily be reproduced by other users, hence a screenshot is not optimal. Here's how you do create one in the future:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
dt = data.table(x = sample(0:5, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.5, rep(0.1,5)), size = 25))
```

Now for your actual problem, you first need to create an id that identifies streaks of not-zeros separated by zeros:

```
dt[, id := rleid(x == 0)]
```

Next, you can compute the maximum per id-group and put them in a new column:

```
dt[, max_val := max(x), by = id]
```

The result is then:

```
        x    id max_val
 1:     0     1       0
 2:     0     1       0
 3:     2     2       2
 4:     1     2       2
 5:     0     3       0
 6:     5     4       5
 7:     1     4       5
 8:     3     4       5
 9:     3     4       5
10:     0     5       0
11:     0     5       0
12:     0     5       0
13:     3     6       3
14:     0     7       0
15:     4     8       4
16:     0     9       0
17:     4    10       4
18:     1    10       4
19:     0    11       0
20:     4    12       4
21:     1    12       4
22:     0    13       0
23:     3    14       3
24:     0    15       0
25:     0    15       0
        x    id max_val
```

Technically, you could do both steps in one using

```
dt[, max_val2 := max(x), by = rleid(x == 0)]
```

but I prefered to show it in separate steps.

Answer (score 2):

A way to do it with dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)

# example of data:
df <- data.frame(x=c(0,0,0,0, 1, 2, 4, 4,0,0,0,0, 2, 34, 23, -1, 0,0,0,0, 43, 23, -11, 4,0, 0, 0))

# create a var "series" that split data by group when finding "first" 0
df <- df %>% mutate(series = cumsum((x != 0 ) &  (lag(x) == 0 )))
# group all 0 values
df$series <- ifelse(df$x == 0, 0, df$series)
# create the var wanted
df<- df %>% group_by(series) %>% mutate(max = max(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
max(matrix[,1])
```

Simply replace 'matrix' with the name of your object and 1 with the column number you wish to test

Comment: Don't think this solves the OP problem. They are searching the max by group.